# Arabic number shows incorrect

Tags: android, arabic

I am working with Arabic Text.
I use Arabic Reshaper,
reshaper doesn't show normally numbers.
can you help us about this problem
[image]

I use [this](https://github.com/agawish/Better-Arabic-Reshaper/tree/master/src/org/amr/arabic) reshaper

```
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ebookfragment, container,false);
            Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"pdms_islamicfont1.2.ttf");
            tv = (TextView ) v.findViewById(R.id.tv);
            tv.setTypeface(typeface);

            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    //        tv.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tv.setTextSize(textSize);

            Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml("<p> ٣١  عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ  </p>");
            tv.setText(ArabicUtilities.reshape(spanned.toString()));
```

Comment: [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: Please show the code you wrote, not a gigantic image most of which is not relevant.

Comment: i've the same problem, how do solve it?

Answer (score 4):

I found this:

```
String filename = 123.doc
String message = string1 + "\u202A" + fileName + "\u202C" + string2;
```

Where string1 and string2 are strings in a RtL language.